# Use rewire to stub function in anonymous export in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, anonymous-function

**Update.  Per the comment below the use case may not have been clear.
To expand, in my app module foo() calls bar() which does some complex logic and returns a boolean.  I'm creating unit tests (Mocha) and trying to rewire the foo() method using `rewire` so I can pass a true/false back into bar() without actually calling bar.

Trying to stub (aka rewire) the bar() method inside an anonymous function.  Is it possible?  I can't see how to overwrite bar() after having tried quite a few different ways.

```
//foobar.js
module.exports = function(config) {

  function bar() {
      console.log('why am i in _%s_ bar?', config)
      //some logic
      return true
    }

  function foo() {
        if (bar()) {
            console.log('should not get here, but someVar is passing: ', someVar)
            return true
        } else {
            console.log('should get here, though, and we still see someVar: ', someVar)
            return false
        }
    }

    return {
        foo: foo,
        bar: bar
    }
}
```

and

```
//rewire_foobar.js
var rewire = require('rewire')
var myModule = rewire(__dirname + '/foobar.js')

myModule.__with__({
    'bar': function(){
      console.log('changing return to false from rewire')
      return false
    },
    'someVar': "abcde"

})(function() {

    var result = myModule('a').foo()
    console.log('result is: ', result)

})
```

gives the results

```
why am i in _a_ bar?
should not get here, but someVar is passing:  abcde
result is:  true
```

`someVar` is being passed through.  But I need to rewire bar() so the logic inside it doesn't get called.

Comment: You may get better help if you explain what you're trying to accomplish.  "rewire() the bar() method inside an anonymous function" is not a meaningful explanation (at least to me).  What are you actually trying to accomplish?  What is the desired end result?

Comment: In my app, bar() does a whole lot more logic and calls other functions but the end result is that it returns true or false. I'm trying to stub the bar() function in my test suite so I can return true/false in different test scenarios. The rewire() is being used in Mocha to test the functionality of foo() without invoking the logic in bar(). Make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround.  My original objective was to test foo() and stub bar() so I can control the results/testing parameter.  It would be great if anyone can come up with a better solution.

In this approach, every single variable and function call will need to be stubbed/rewired. That's okay for my testing but might not be feasible for all solutions.

My workaround is:

1. Write the foo() function to a temporary file.  (In testing, this
   should/could be done in a before() block).
2. Test the function as a standalone function.
3. Delete the test temporary file.

Here's the code for foobar.spec.js:

```
var rewire = require('rewire')
var foobar = require('./foobar.js')
var fs = require('fs')

//extracts the function to test and exports it as temp()
//could be done in a before() block for testing
var completeHack = 'exports.temp = ' + foobar().foo.toString()
//write the function to a temporary file
fs.writeFileSync(__dirname + '/temp.js', completeHack , 'utf8')

//rewire the extracted function 
var myModule = rewire(__dirname + '/temp.js')

myModule.__with__({
  //and stub/rewire and variables
    'bar': function(){
      console.log('changing return to false from rewire')
      return false
    },
    'someVar': "abcde",
    'config': 'not really important'

})(function() {
    //and test for our result
    var result = myModule.temp()
    console.log('result is: ', result)

})

//and finally delete the temp file.  Should be put in afterEach() testing function
fs.unlinkSync(__dirname + '/temp.js')
```